# Mail app stuck at "in progress"

Tags: email, imap

I'm trying to configure the mail app in Android 4/ICS with my IMAP account, but I get stuck at "in progress" after setting up the SMTP server.

These are the exact steps I'm going through:

1. Open the mail app.
2. Go to settings.
3. Click the plus sign in the top right hand side corner.
4. Enter my email address and password. Check "Push notification" and "Send from this account by default". Click "Next".
5. It says "Retrieving account information" for a while before giving up and asking me "POP3 or IMAP account?" I choose IMAP.
6. I enter the correct IMAP server name and check "Use SSL". The port changes to 993, which is correct. I leave NTLM authentication unchecked.
7. I enter the correct SMTP server, which just happens to be smtp.euromail.se. I leave the port at its default of 25, no SSL, no authentication.

Now it just sits there saying "In progress..." forever. I've tried starting over several times, but it always chokes at the last step. How do I solve this?  These same settings work just fine in K-9 Mail.

Comment: Are you in the Mail app choosing accounts or in the Accounts area of the Settings list?

Comment: @Dez: The Accounts area.

Comment: @damd: Per your flag: It would be better to edit this question than to create a new one if you have new details/clarity to add.

Comment: There is No 'Automatically Configure' box to check or un-check in Ice Cream Sadwich 4.0.3! Mail no longer Syncs even though set up as Push and when deleted from Phone, the emails remain on the Server. There is also no option anywhere in the Settings to 'Delete email from the Server and the Handset.'

Answer (score 5):

1. Open Email.
2. Enter your email credentials (the address and the password).
3. Choose Manual setup.
4. Choose IMAP.
5. Enter server settings.

Comment: There is no "Manual setup" choice in Android 4.0.

Comment: What mail program are you trying to configure? Gmail, your carrier's 3rd party app, or the native email app?

Comment: The native e-mail app.

Comment: If there's no 'manual setup', untick the 'automatically configure' check box and then click Next.

Answer (score 3):

You need to go into the Mail application and set up an account through there.  The Accounts area is for syncing accounts for the phone (like your Gmail address).